# Как оставлять генерированые коды в заказе в личном кабинете пользователя WorPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Код генерирует 6-значные числа на основе номера заказа и добавляет две случайные. Количество кодов - сумма заказа, делёная на 3000. Всё это прекрасно отображается в админской части заказов WP, отправляется на почту. Но в личном кабинете, на сайте не отображается в отдельном заказе. Что можно изменить?

````
    $random_number = rand(10, 99);
    return str_pad($order_id . $random_number, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

function generate_order_codes($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $total_amount = (float) $order->get_total();
    $code_count = (int) floor($total_amount / 3000);
    $codes = array();

    $order_number = $order->get_order_number(); 

    for ($i = 0; $i < $code_count; $i++) {
        $code = generate_code($order_number);
        $codes[] = $code;
    }

   
    $order->update_meta_data('generated_codes', implode(',', $codes));
    $order->save();
}
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'generate_order_codes');

function add_generated_codes_to_order_email($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email) {
    $generated_codes = $order->get_meta('generated_codes');
    if ($generated_codes) {
        echo '<h3>Коды для розыгрыша на этот заказ:</h3>';
        echo '<p>' . $generated_codes . '</p>';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'add_generated_codes_to_order_email', 10, 4); ```
````